# MAAS can't download boot images

Tags: boot, server, juju, maas

On my MAAS Gui and "Images" I've got these errors

Boot image import process not started. Nodes will not be able to provision without boot images. Visit the boot images page to start the import.

```
Failed to import images from boot source 
http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='maas.ubuntu.com', port=80): 
Max retries exceeded with url:
/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson 
(Caused by : [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

and 
    `Error: No boot sources provide Ubuntu images.`

So I tried to do lot of commands.

I did:

`maas root node-groups import-boot-images`

nothing appended.

and:

`maas root boot-resources import`

nothing appended.

and:

`maas-import-pxe-files --sources-file ****`

but I don't know which sources file used.

I tried everything and I don't get any images, same goes for the web ui.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The import operating is dependent on the version of MAAS that you are using. I would recommend using version 1.7 or higher. In version 1.7 starting the images import can be done on the images page or using the API.

```
maas root boot-resources import
```

The error you are seeing is because MAAS is unable to reach maas.ubuntu.com to download the images. Check your upstream network connectivity on the MAAS server to make sure it can access that location. The /var/log/maas/regiond.log will also contain more information on this error and could be helpful in diagnosing the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific : So I have installed the last version of MAAS from the repository 1.7. So I'm agree MAAS has a problem to reach maas.ubuntu.com and I don't know why. But from my MAAS server I can ping, wget, dig "maas.ubuntu.com". I can also download and install everything I want on my MAAS server. SO what's wrong ? I have also a proxy but everything is set correctly on my /etc/environement and my /etc/atp/atp.conf. I don't kwon what to do .. any ideas ? help ?

Comment: Did you set that same proxy on the MAAS settings page? You need to also set the proxy address on the settings page for the importing to use the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I can set the proxy address on the settings page with this type of address "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/" but MAAS don't want to use this type of address "http://user_name:password@myproxy.server.com:8080/"  Is it normal or not ?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't want to use this address? Is it raising an error?

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this error and like you, tried all possible solutions. Turned out that it was much simpler than I had imagined. Going trough `/var/log/maas/regiond.log` just after typing the command

```
maas <user> boot-resources import
```

Gave me this error:

> key 476CF100 was created 152222276 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)\n gpg: Can't check signature: timestamp conflict\n")

Since this many seconds ammount to 4.8 years, I decided to check my system time with `timedatectl`:

```
Local time: Tue 2008-01-01 02:27:44 BRST
```

After rebooting the machine and correctly configuring the date settings in the BIOS, I got:

```
Local time: Tue 2016-04-05 16:01:50 BRT
```

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled firewall, your firewall is blocking port `8000` which is used by MAAS proxy to download images. [MAAS docs for version 2.9 say](https://maas.io/docs/snap/2.9/ui/proxy#heading--internal-proxy-maas-proxy):

> ### Internal proxy (MAAS proxy)
>
> MAAS provides an internal proxy server. Although it is set up to work well with APT/package requests, it is effectively an HTTP caching proxy server. If you configure the MAAS region controller as the default gateway for the machines it manages then the proxy will work transparently (on TCP port 3128). Otherwise, machines will need to access it on TCP port 8000.